# I have to write Regex which allowed only @#$% as special symbols and not allow others like ?><`~ symbols

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, regex

I have to write Regex which allowed only `!@#$%^&` as special symbols and alphabets and numbers and not allow other special symbols like ?><`~ symbols.

I tried with: `(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&]`

This ask me to enter at least one number and one character and one special symbol which I mentioned in regex, this works great.

But I want when I entered other special symbols like `~? etc then it must show error message for invalid string.

Comment: OK, Regexes themselves don't provide error messages.  Are you referring to the RegularExpressionValidator?

Comment: yes i am using regular expression validator

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a regular expression that fits those criteria, here's one:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&]*
```

This will allow digits, upper and lower-case characters, and the special characters indicated.

It doesn't impose any particular order on them.  If you need something more complex, like one number followed by one character followed by a special symbol, say so in the comments.

Now, as for the message:  sounds like what you need is a `RegularExpressionValidator`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but when i entered the ?~` etc special symbol it also except them, what i want is regex should not except the other special symbol (which are not defined in regex)

Comment: Do you want it to respond instantly to the incorrect symbol, as soon as you type it, or only when you submit the page?

Comment: Oh, and do you want it to refuse to allow the symbol to be entered (show a message, but the textbox contents don't change)?  That would require some javascript in addition to a `RegularExpressionValidator`.

Comment: I want to only show a message that input text can not contain the special symbol ~`? it can only  contain what we defined in regex.